# How could I connect a public port to a different internal port?

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, port-forwarding

I'm setting up a 2nd Plex server and I've decided to use port `32401` instead of port `32400` since I already have a Plex server running on that port.

My issue is that Plex wants `[publicip]:32401` to point to `[localip]:32400` but my router can only point public ports to the same local ports (so no `[publicip]:32401 -> [localip]:32400`).

Is there a way for Linux to listen to port `32401` and "reroute" it internally to port 32400? I've seen similar iptables commands but none fit my exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this iptables rule

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d LOCAL_IP -p tcp --dport 32401 -j DNAT --to-destination LOCAL_IP:32400
```

along with this kernel configuration

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

and all traffic for LOCAL_IP:32401 will be forwarded to LOCAL_IP:32400

Answer (score 0):

I decided to RTFM and found my fix on the Arch Wiki's Plex page. By doing this command, I was able to reroute port `32401` to `32400`:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 32401 -j REDIRECT --to-port 32400`